# Encontrar por estabelecimento e não por rua GOOGLE MAPS

Tags: javascript, google, maps

Eu estou usando o seguinte código para encontrar ruas no google maps, mas tenho a necessidade de encontrar estabelecimentos, aqui segue o [link](http://caixapretadasaude.org.br/painel/maps/)  do projeto, estando tendo dificuldades para encontrar os locais.

```
var geocoder;
var map;
var marker; function initialize() {
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-18.8800397, -47.05878999999999);
    var options = {
        zoom: 5,
        center: latlng,
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapa"), options);

geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    draggable: true,
});

marker.setPosition(latlng);}$(document).ready(function () { initialize();

function carregarNoMapa(endereco) {
    geocoder.geocode({ 'address': endereco + ', Brasil', 'region': 'BR' }, function (results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            if (results[0]) {
                var latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
                var longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();

                $('#txtEndereco').val(results[0].formatted_address);
                $('#txtLatitude').val(latitude);
                $('#txtLongitude').val(longitude);

                var location = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);
                marker.setPosition(location);
                map.setCenter(location);
                map.setZoom(16);
            }
        }
    })
}

$("#btnEndereco").click(function() {
    if($(this).val() != "")
        carregarNoMapa($("#txtEndereco").val());
})

$("#txtEndereco").blur(function() {
    if($(this).val() != "")
        carregarNoMapa($(this).val());
})

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'drag', function () {
    geocoder.geocode({ 'latLng': marker.getPosition() }, function (results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            if (results[0]) {  
                $('#txtEndereco').val(results[0].formatted_address);
                $('#txtLatitude').val(marker.getPosition().lat());
                $('#txtLongitude').val(marker.getPosition().lng());
            }
        }
    });
});

$("#txtEndereco").autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        geocoder.geocode({ 'address': request.term + ', Brasil', 'region': 'BR' }, function (results, status) {
            response($.map(results, function (item) {
                return {
                    label: item.formatted_address,
                    value: item.formatted_address,
                    latitude: item.geometry.location.lat(),
                    longitude: item.geometry.location.lng()
                }
            }));
        })
    },
    select: function (event, ui) {
        $("#txtLatitude").val(ui.item.latitude);
        $("#txtLongitude").val(ui.item.longitude);
        var location = new google.maps.LatLng(ui.item.latitude, ui.item.longitude);
        marker.setPosition(location);
        map.setCenter(location);
        map.setZoom(16);
    }
});

$("form").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var endereco = $("#txtEndereco").val();
    var latitude = $("#txtLatitude").val();
    var longitude = $("#txtLongitude").val();

    alert("Endereço: " + endereco + "\nLatitude: " + latitude + "\nLongitude: " + longitude);
}); });
```

Comment: Aonde estão esses locais? não entendi muito bem?

Comment: O script que esta acima está buscando por rua, quero buscar por places(Locais). Ex: Hospital, lojas etc. deixei um link de exemplo, se possível faça uma pesquisa.

Comment: Me da um exemplo de local que ao pesquisar deveria aparecer.

Comment: Ex: Hospital 9 de Julho, Hospital Santa Casa, Hospital Campo Limpo

Comment: Se você faz isso no google maps, ele acha. Reparei que toda vez que eu busco ele auto completa, tenta desativar o auto completar e busca por Hospital 9 de Julho

Comment: Já tinha tentando isso e não deu certo, de desativar o auto complete.

Comment: Eu tenho pesquisar por (Hospital 9 de Julho) e sai (Ladeira do Hospital, 9 - Nazaré, Salvador - BA, 40050-420, Brasil)

Comment: Sim, porque está procurando por endereço e não por locais.

Comment: Amigo, tira tudo isso de autocomplete. provável que se voce pesquisar Hospital Sao Paulo como ADDRES, vai achar.

Comment: Já tinha feito isso e não deu certo, mudei o addres para places e também não funcionou.

Comment: OK, se só acha por addres faça o seguinte, pega todos os hospitais, coloca em um array com NOME + ENDEREÇO. quando a pessoa pesquisar por HOSPITAL XPTO voce vai no array acha ele pelo NOME recupera o ENDEREÇO e procura por ele.

Comment: Neste caso, não seria possível, pois não tenho essa relação de hospitais, essa pesquisa seria para alimentar a minha base de dados.

Comment: Alguma novidade?

Comment: Sim, eu acabei utilizando outro api da Google para fazer, em breve postarei o código para que possam dar uma olhada.

Comment: Legal cara, parabéns aí @Henrique S. Santos

Comment: Você já tentou usar esse script http://gmap3.net ? Tem um exemplo no código fonte que faz isso, na pasta [examples] rode o [autocomplete] ele funciona por locais e endereços. Pode ser uma referência... que lhe permita evoluir com a solução.